# Float object is not subscriptable with enumerate but works with range and if-else

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand why I can't use enumerate like I want to when trying to compare a str value to float in order to execute code in an if-else block.  For example, here is what works:

```
testa = [23.12, 34.15, 25.12, 34.23]

if testa[0] == 'word':
    print('It's is a string')
else:
    print('Not a string')
```

This successfully prints "Not a string".  This next code block also works:

```
for i in range(len(testa)):
    if testa[i] == 'word':
        print('Its a string')
    else:
        print('Not a string')
```

The above two code blocks work as expected.  Now, I want to use enumerate:

```
for i, number in enumerate(testa, start=0):
    if number[i] == 'word':
        print("Its a string")
    else:
        print("Not a string")
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

It's important that I'm able to keep up with specific indices so I thought I could just feed it `i` for the index counter and let enumerate take care of incrementing it on its own, but something else is happening here that I'm not seeing.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what `enumerate` does. My guess is that you wanted to run `if testa[i] == 'word'`.

Comment: @slallum I need to iterate over the list and test every element inside it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `enumerate` the number you get for `value` is already `testa[i]`. It is the element of the matrix, a float, so you can't index it. Change it to `if number == 'word'`

Comment: I could have swore that I actually tried this before I posted to SO.  Either I got confused or screwed up the test code somehow.  Thanks, I'll try it out as soon as I get home!

Answer (score 1):

Use `number` instead of `number[i]`.

Remember, you're already iterating over testa.